# How do plugin updates work?

Tags: plugins, multisite, plugin-jetpack

I have just inherited a MultiSite install with about 100 plugins, many of them out of date, and I have noticed that they dont seem to be getting update notifications. And yes, I have checked for updates from the Network Admin dashboard

For instance, the jetpack plug is currently at 3.5.3 and the version currently located on wordpress.org is at 3.7.2 which includes a bug fix we need BUT there is no notification of an update in the dashboard.

Is there a filter or setting which prevents these update checks? Is there a way to update it manually (without uploading the folders via FTP) or to force WordPress to check for the update? Or is this a feature of MultiSite?

Comment: Not a normal feature of multisite. What happens when you click on "View Details" on a plugin? Does the pop-up correctly indicate whether the version installed is the newest one?

Comment: You mean when I goto the "add new" plugins page, search for a plugin in question and then click "view details"? All it does it open a modal with an iframe to the plugin's page on wordpress.org.

Comment: Normally, the modal will say at the bottom right whether the version installed is up to date or not. I wonder if one of those 100 plug-ins - or a function elsewhere - is set to disable update notifications (something that someone with 100 plug-ins might like!) or is interfering with updates. If nothing seems obvious, you might try de-activating all plug-ins. If you're still not getting update notifications, you might have to make sure that this core functionality hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: That is a great point, there are about 20 plugins in here from the previous developers, none of which have any sort of documentation. I'll start checking those out. Thanks!

Comment: It also wouldn't be surprising if one or more plug-ins had been hacked, and that the developer, judging that the current state of the installation was adequate and not in need of updating, didn't want an uninformed user updating over whatever had been done, breaking the hack. So, if the whole thing is working relatively well, you might want to be sure to make a good copy of plugins and theme files before letting new updates happen. No telling what might break!